# PHPMailer fails to send email via gmail SMTP service used by an organisation

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send Emails from the Platform for every successful registration. I am using PHPMailer and this is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->Username   = "<gmail login id>";
$mail->Password   = "<something>";

$mail->setFrom('<subdomain>.<organisation domain>', '<org name>');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body = 'Hi! This is Test Message.';
if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
        echo "Message sent!";
}
```

The organisation uses Gmail services for email.

From the code Above, I am getting following error:

> Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

This is my first time dealing with PHPMailer so please help me spot my mistake(s) here and I have tried several solutions from google and SO.. But none seems to work

Thanks Everyone :)

Comment: Read the docs the error points you to. It answers this exact question, which has also been answered many times on here. Base your code on the Gmail example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMailer email not sending gmail smtp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502393/phpmailer-email-not-sending-gmail-smtp)

Comment: nope it is not, That question is very different from regular gmail smtp. I am trying to use an organisation's email which is linked with GMAIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Gmail smtp settings reference**](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854)

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing in your email account to yes in **Allow access for less secure apps**

look this
https://help.crucial.com.au/hc/en-gb/articles/214180837-Enabling-Less-Secure-Apps

Answer (score 0):

Regarding https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600
Port 25 is only open on aspmx.l.google.com
You should use Port 587 (TLS) or 465 (SSL).