# PHPMailer Software caused connection abort

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails from a local XAMPP instance on my Mac running Sierra 10.12 using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). When I go to send the test email utilising Gmail's SMTP server(s), I get a '53' software caused connection abort error as seen below:

> 2017-04-30 02:59:56   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Software caused connection abort (53) 2017-04-30 02:59:56  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I have tried their troubleshooting guide and found nothing else relating to this issue, so I assume it is pretty infrequent.

The code below is based on [PHPMailer's Gmail Example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) which is strange because it is throwing the error. I have obviously hidden my emails and password for StackOverflow:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer; // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom("email@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("myotheremail@hotmail.com");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019308/phpmailer-fails-to-send-email-via-gmail-smtp-service-used-by-an-organisation/43019407#43019407 You are using wrong settings.. You should use `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Comment: @SahilGulati thanks for the response. That seemed to fix the original issue but now PHPMailer seems to be hanging/loading when trying to send. Chrome is saying "Waiting for localhost" while the page loads but I have left it for over 15 minutes to no avail. Any ideas on this? Cheers

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it by changing `$mail->IsSMTP();` to `$mail->IsMail();` which seems to send the mail instantly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stumble upon this thread:
Thanks to [Sahil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5423014/sahil-gulati), the issue was being caused by a setting I was using incorrectly. Instead of `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` I should've been using `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`.

Another issue I discovered was when this was resolved, the mail was taking an extremely long time to send/getting stuck on load which caused a timeout. This was fixed by changing `$mail->IsSMTP();` to `$mail->IsMail();`.

Cheers

Comment: Be aware that neither of these are really fixes. You say you based your code in the Gmail example, and provide the right link, yet your code looks like a very old version of it. Switching to ismail isn't fixing the problem - you're making SMTP "work" by not using SMTP. You're just relaying via localhost, which may run into the same problem at a later stage that's harder to see.