# PHPMailer can not connect to the SMTP host

Tags: php, html, smtp

I have this form that sends emails to the email.In localhost it works fine, when I upload it to host it gives me the following bug.

> Could not access file: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

email.php

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$portal = $_POST['portal'];
$piso = $_POST['piso'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$incidencia = $_POST['incidencia'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$archivo = $_FILES['adjunto'];

require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = $email;
$mail->FromName = $first_name; 
$mail->AddAddress("micrreo@gmail.com"); // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.


$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);    
$mail->Subject  =  "Incidencia ";

$mail->Body     =  
    "Esto es un correo generado desde la web, si quiere mas informacion contacte con: correo@gmail.com \n<br". 
    "Nombre: $first_name \n<br />".    
    "Apellido: $last_name \n<br />".  
    "Portal: $portal \n<br />".
    "Piso: $piso \n<br />".
    "Email: $email \n<br />".
    "Telefono: $phone \n<br />".  
    "Incidencia: $incidencia \n<br />".
    "Mensaje: $message \n<br />";

$mail->AddAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']);



$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";  // Servidor de Salida.
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "micorreo@gmail.com";  // Correo Electrónico
$mail->Password = "mipasswd"; // Contraseña


if ($mail->Send()){
    echo "<script>alert('bien');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario')</script>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit();
}

?>
```

sorry for my english, I'm spanish
Thank you very much to anyone who helps me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMailer email not sending gmail smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502393/phpmailer-email-not-sending-gmail-smtp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Comment: Hello,i see this post ,but my problem is different.I already have done what that post indicates

Comment: I think my problem is that I try to send a file to the mail,but i dont now

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a lack of SSL support in the PHP version of your host, as it's written here :
[PHPMailer: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

So, check in your php.ini file if extension=php_openssl.dll is enabled.

If it's disabled, don't forget to restart the web server after enabling this extension.

Hope it will help you.

EDIT after your answer :

Although I'm not sure it can help, you can try to replace the following line :

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";
```

by those lines :

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Also, if it doesn't work with SSL, you can try to use 'tls' instead of 'ssl', and 
to replace the port 465 by the port 587.

If it still doesn't work, you can add the following line that will give you more information on your error :

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Comment: the file extension=php_openssl.dll is enabled,the problem is other

Comment: Just a precision : I meant that the php_openssl extension must be checked on your host and not locally. So, if your host is a Linux OS, the extension name is php_openssl.so.